# Why any update is not working in a js file with ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest, rendering

I am working with a php file name users. For this I was to write some javascript program . Initially the javascript code work well .But after updating the javascript code ,they are no longer working.

Here the php file(users.php):

```
 <div class="wrapper">
  <section class="users">
    <header>
      <?php 
        include_once("php/config.php");
        $sql = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE unique_id={$_SESSION['unique_id']}");
        if( mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0 ){
          $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
        }          
      ?>
      <div class="content">
        <img src="php/images/<?php echo $row['img'] ?>" alt="" />
        <div class="details">
          <span><?php echo $row['fname']." ".$row['lname'] ?></span>
          <p><?php echo $row['status'] ?></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="#" class="logout">Logout</a>
    </header>
    <div class="search">
      <span class="text">Select an user to start chat</span>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter name to search..." />
      <button><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div class="users-list">         
     
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
<script src="javascript/users.js"></script>
```

Here the js file(users.js):

```
          //1st part
          const searchBar = document.querySelector(".users .search input");
         searchBtn = document.querySelector(".users .search button");

         searchBtn.onclick = () => {
            searchBar.classList.toggle("active");
            searchBar.focus();
             searchBtn.classList.toggle("active");
          };    


         //2nd part
         setInterval(() => {
           console.log("habib");
            // let's start Ajax
              let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); //creating xml object
              xhr.open("GET", "php/users.php", true);
              xhr.onload = () => {
                 if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                    if (xhr.status === 200) {
                        let data = xhr.response;
                         console.log(data);
                     }
                   }
              };
              // we have to send through ajax to php
             xhr.send();
       }, 500);
```

First time when I wrote the 1st part js program ,they work well .But after writing 2nd part they are not working .I faced the same problem previously.Restarting my pc ,the problem wased solved.
But I want to know why this happen?

And the console shows the following error..
[image]

Comment: I am suggesting use jquery ajax

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the correct answer, but maybe it's only an issue with your browser, expecially if you use **Chrome**. Usually Chrome tend to cache a lot JS and CSS files for later referencing. This is good for users, that need to download these files once, and can load pages faster since they already have the files, but it is a nightmare for web developers. To fix this issue you can:

1. Force reload the page using **Ctrl + F5**
2. Change the file name, so Chrome is forced to reload the page
3. Change browser, and use some lighter browsers, like **Edge** or **Firefox**

To check this issue, you can simply open JS and CSS files in your browser, make some changes and try to reload your code; if you use Chrome you'll see that the code will remain the same, except for one of the above solutions